# How to figure out what stored proceedure is being called through a executable file in MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, dts

I'm a newbie into Java. And currrently i'm working on an enhancement project. I'm struck at a point in my analysis. I gotta figure out how the stored procs are being called and what all parameters are being passed. As of now I know that a process is executing an executable from a directory on the server. This  executable Might(not sure- Assuming) be calling the stored proc. My doubt is how do I figure what this executable is doing?

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exeString);

exeString has the path where my Executable file resides. Not sure if the name of the executable holds any significance here, anyway its "SqlDMOCall".Along with the executable, there is a DLL file. I tried Decompiling it through ILSPY only to fail.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: try using sql server profiler against the database, it will trace each call to the databse and show you what was passed in

Answer (score 0):

You can query SQL server to see exactly what is being executed on it. While your application is running, run this query to see what it is doing:

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```